# How to get the Maven local repo location?

Tags: maven-2, maven

Is there a way to get the Maven local repo location?

Using the following command you can force Maven to use a specific setting file:

```
 mvn -s < path to settings file >
```

I know you can edit `settings.xml` file to set a repository location, but can I get the current default value with some Maven command?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

If you want just the local repo, try this:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -v '\[INFO\]'
```

**EDIT**

I'm revisiting this after years because recent versions of the Maven help plugin introduced a useful parameter for the `evaluate` goal called [`forceStdout`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html#forceStdout) that allows us to remove the need to grep the output:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout
```

Comment: I think you intended to `| grep -v '\[INFO\]'`   Your regex has nasty side effects.

Comment: both versions work for me, what do you mean by "nasty side effects"?

Comment: @adutra Your regex specifies a match group consisting of the upper case characters I, N, F, and O. So it will match either of those lines: INFO, OFNI, I, F, N etc. Try it out `echo -e "INFO\nOFNI\nI\nIfoobar" | grep '[INFO]'`

Comment: This will not work if you have maven warnings or it downloads dependencies. The following grep, which searches for absolute file paths, should work on both unix and windows: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -E '^([a-zA-Z]:|/)'`

Comment: @SiXoS yours also didn't work, in my case, mvn threw warnings when [INFO] Scanning for projects....  and didn't match any thing when the output gets grepped.

Comment: @Sajuuk If you have download messages you should turn batch mode on, and to remove warning messages, you could use a regex, so the whole command would be: mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -B | grep -v -E '\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\]'

Comment: @adutra ...  Thanks for that.  These days I ride along and use the default repo location: `${user.home}/.m2/repository`  or `$HOME/.m2/repository` and use a SymLink to point to a location of my choice.  It wasn't worth the overhead of constantly tracking down the settings file.  These days I use `SDKMAN` so using a default setting is a no brainer really.  You've helped me unravel where the repo. "was" so I may move it. Great work!

Answer (score 59):

Yes, you can get it with the `-X` or `--debug` option, e.g. `mvn -X`

```
...
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Maven\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\segphault\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Repo
...
```

Answer (score 46):

The Maven Help plugin will show local settings, including the local repository path.

You want the command:

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

Output will show settings in XML format.  Look for the localRepository element:

```
<localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">/home/jrs/.mavenRepo</localRepository>
```

Comment: looks like if it throws warning, the output will not be in XML format.

Answer (score 28):

In the [meantime](https://blogs.apache.org/maven/entry/apache-maven-help-plugin-version1) you can do that in a simpler way:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout
```

You can also directly use that to assign that a shell variable like this:

```
RESULT=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout)
```

Important note: Use most recent version of Maven and of course most recent vesion of maven-help-plugin...

This will contain the result without a new line etc.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer as it gives a solution that yeild a cleaner result than any other solution proposed so far.

Comment: This is broken on at least some platforms/configurations. For me (fc 28, Maven 3.5.2), -q makes it yield no output, though without -q, the property is there, but must be grepped out.

Answer (score 7):

### For windows users

Usually it's in: `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.m2\repository`.
However the `mvn help:effective-settings` command will surely show the local path in response xml.

Comment: More general: `${user.home}/.m2/repository` is the default that can be overridden in [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). `mvn help:effective-settings`  has been mentioned in an answer here more than 6 years earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6670563/1744774.

Answer (score 6):

It should be in the /home/.m2 directory, the folder is probably hidden. So, you'll need to Ctrl+H to see hidden folders.