# eclipse not updating output folder after compile

Tags: eclipse

I have a maven project on eclipse with jrebel plugin installed. Hot-deploy used to work perfectly last week but now only xhtml pages are hot-deploy. When a java class is changed it doesn't hot deploy.

What I noticed is when I changed a file and save eclipse will automatically build it. But the output folder file is not updated base on file stamp that's why jrebel doesn't pick it up. When I run maven-install it compiles everything and all the java classes are reloaded which is not efficient.

So the main problem is eclipse newly compiled classes don't go to output folder (project/target/classes), even though it's set in Build Path.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several minutes of testing, I found a warning on a jar file specifically guava being downloaded as dependency. I've delete in repo to be redownloaded and after that jrebel is working again.

So the problem is a corrupted jar that causes everything to be rebuild even if only a single file is changed. But the weird part is there's no corrupted file error.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the content of your local Maven repository is cached for a day. This can happen even for bad downloads (as I experienced). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7421893/44089 for a short description of how to work around that.

Comment: But how would you know that 1 of those jars is corrupt? In my case it's not obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't have any clue for that. In my case, those were compile time dependencies, so the build broke, which I obviously noticed.