# maven Error resolving version for plugin maven-eclipse-plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I recently encoutered one error when i built my job on jenkins,
the same build was success in few week, but yesterday the build fails with the following error :

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-  eclipse-plugin' from the repositories [local (/cip/home/jenkins-V1/.m2/repository-Project), central (http://mrm.fr.company.com/Project-virtual), snapshots (http://mrm.fr.company.com/Project-virtual)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /cip/home/jenkins-V1/workspace/project/pom.xml to project.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

For information : 
The plugin : maven-eclipse-plugin is existing in the virtual repository of the project, then i don't know why the build fails... , but when the build fails they generate one file in the location of this plugin on the .m2 repository : the file generated is : resolver-status.properties this file  contain :

```
#NOTE: This is an internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Thu Dec 17 12:29:25 CET 2015
maven-metadata-snapshots.xml.lastUpdated=1450351765625
maven-metadata-central.xml.error=
maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated=1450351765601
maven-metadata-snapshots.xml.error=
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in Eclipse (not Jenkins), and I solved it by [clearing my maven cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache).

Nestor Urquiza may have the [explanation](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/06/error-getting-pom-for.html): the "pom.xml file gets somehow modified". He gives further help in case clearing the cache doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of directly linking out, summarize what specifically helped in those answers as well as linking out for additional information.