# Jenkins Error resolving version for plugin maven-eclipse-plugin

Tags: jenkins, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, maven-plugin

I recently encoutered one error when i build my job on jenkins,
configuration of the job : jdk version : 1.6_23, maven version : 3.0.5 , cmd maven :  clean install.

the same build was in success the last week, but today the build is failing, i didn't make any change on configuration of jenkins or in the source code of the project, the last week we didn't need to specify the version of the plugin maven-eclipse-plugin and today i have the error in below when i don't specify the version of the plugin in the pom.xml.

can anyone help me, thanks in advance  !

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-  eclipse-plugin' from the repositories [local (/cip/home/jenkins-V1/.m2/repository-Project), central (http://mrm.fr.company.com/Project-virtual), snapshots (http://mrm.fr.company.com/Project-virtual)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /cip/home/jenkins-V1/workspace/project/pom.xml to project.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

Regards,
Youssef

Comment: Your question might be the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333640/maven-error-resolving-version-for-plugin-maven-eclipse-plugin-in-jenkins).

Comment: You might be asking the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333640/maven-error-resolving-version-for-plugin-maven-eclipse-plugin-in-jenkins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two workaround for this errr :

1. Execute sonar with maven and add `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar` to choose the correct version of `sonar-maven-plugin`
2. Fix the version on sonar part in manage jenkins.