# Import error Spring Boot 1.4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've just started learning Spring framework. However, I have a problem that I can't find any solution to.

When I download a project from start.spring.io (Spring Boot 1.4.0) and import it into STS there is an error in the Application class:

> The import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication cannot be resolved

However, when I download it for Spring Boot 1.3.8. it works perfectly. Well, I could use the 1.3.8. one, but since a lot of code examples are for 1.4.0. I cannot move on with tutorials.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted download of one of Boot's jar files. Try cleaning out your build system's cache (you don't say whether you're using Maven or Gradle) and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm using Maven. How to clean system's cache?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache

Comment: I used tips from your link as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update and it worked. Thanks for help!