# Unable to run springboot application: The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm new in developing with springBoot and I want to run an example to learn how to write some Data in an elasticsearch database. So I donwloaded the git example from here:

> https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-data-elastic-example-2

So when I open it I get an error:

:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

```
2018-08-08 07:42:01.935  INFO 3898 --- [           main] c.t.e.SpringElasticDemoApplication       : Starting SpringElasticDemoApplication on phil-VirtualBox with PID 3898 (/home/phil/eclipse/workspace/spring-data-elastic-example-2-master/target/classes started by phil in /home/phil/eclipse/workspace/spring-data-elastic-example-2-master)
2018-08-08 07:42:01.944  INFO 3898 --- [           main] c.t.e.SpringElasticDemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-08 07:42:02.078  INFO 3898 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2c34f934: startup date [Wed Aug 08 07:42:02 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-08 07:42:02.949  INFO 3898 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-08-08 07:42:03.085  INFO 3898 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=elasticConfiguration; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/techprimers/elastic/config/ElasticConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-08-08 07:42:03.115  INFO 3898 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-08-08 07:42:03.137  INFO 3898 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.techprimers.elastic.repository.UsersRepository.
2018-08-08 07:42:03.160  INFO 3898 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2018-08-08 07:42:03.608  INFO 3898 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$175e2308] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-08 07:42:03.750  WARN 3898 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
2018-08-08 07:42:03.758 ERROR 3898 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
```

I guess it is a maven problem so I went to my .pom directory of the project and executed `mvn verify`and this is the error protocol

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0;

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

Sorry but the stacktrace is to long to put in here.
I thought that with adding the `spring-boot-starter-web dependency`I have the stuff needed included.
Here is the pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.techprimers.elastic</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-elastic-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-elastic-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So I followed the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665445/9326543 but nothing changed.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I added the following dependency and its worked, Even I do not need any validation, maybe the Java update caused this issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

How did you run it? I've checked out this example and used `mvnw spring-boot:run` and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I open it in eclipse as Run As->Spring Boot App

Comment: This is the Error I get
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-elastic-demo: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed;

Comment: I completly removed maven and reinstalled it. Now it works.