# Spring Boot: SpringApplication.run causes org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I haven't use Java in many years, but now I'd like to use Java/Groovy for web development. Spring Boot seems to be the most recommended option to use as a framework these days, so I'm trying to get my first Hello World to run following the course *Creating Your First Spring Boot Application* on pluralsight.com.

I used Groovy for console apps in the past. I've used Eclipse, but I don't have any experience with Maven or Gradle. Now I installed Spring Tool Suite 3.

I couldn't get the first sample application to run, instead the program terminates with an error message (see below). I'm supposed to open `http://localhost:8080` in the browser, but no server is found. Below are my files.

Can you help me spot the problem? I'm on a Mac and the project is set up as a Maven project in STS.

**App.java**

```
package com.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // System.out.println("test") does work
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <name>das-boot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2019-01-03 22:32:08.034  INFO 77010 --- [           main] com.boot.App                             : Starting App on mb12.local with PID 77010 (/Users/pida/sts-workspace/das-boot/target/classes started by pida in /Users/pida/sts-workspace/das-boot)
2019-01-03 22:32:08.040  INFO 77010 --- [           main] com.boot.App                             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-03 22:32:08.160  INFO 77010 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5032714f: startup date [Thu Jan 03 22:32:08 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-03 22:32:09.263  INFO 77010 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/pida/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-01-03 22:32:09.799  WARN 77010 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
2019-01-03 22:32:09.818 ERROR 77010 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.boot.App.main(App.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:195) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]

// Much output omitted

2019-01-03 22:32:09.823  INFO 77010 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
```

Comment: To start, you're using seriously outdated software versions. STS is now on version 4, and you should use either Boot 1.5.x or 2.0.x. (Creating a project from start.spring.io or from the Eclipse Boot wizard will get you the latest versions.)

Comment: Your local maven repository may have corrupted. This might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542986/multiple-errors-when-starting-server-with-spring-boot

Comment: Instead, follow this course to learn Spring boot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msXL2oDexqw

Comment: Thanks. I chose those versions to be able to follow the course. I might follow the course mentioned by Nikhil after finishing the Pluralsight one which is not that much older (34 vs. 25 months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.3 does not support java 11 which looking at that reflective access warning seems likely. Java 11 is only supported in Spring Boot 2.1.

Either use JDK8 or upgrade that application to use Spring Boot 2.1.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

> By default, Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.1.5 or above. You can use Spring Boot with Java 6 with some additional configuration. See Section 79.9, “How to use Java 6” for more details. Explicit build support is provided for Maven (3.2+) and Gradle (1.12+).
>   [Tip]
>
> Although you can use Spring Boot with Java 6 or 7, we generally recommend Java 8 if at all possible.

As mentioned I'd recommend not using any 1.x version for Spring Boot. It's end of life in August of this year.

Comment: Thanks, everything working using JDK 8. I try to stick with the recommended tools for the short course I'm following, but I'll keep in mind to switch so Spring Boot 2 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring Boot it comes up with inbuilt Tomcat webserver. Try to change the port nber by adding the property in the application.properties file.

server.port=8090

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Services, Components, Entites and etc are all Java Beans

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Java bean : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11407040/7418314