# While Starting Web Service Iam getting error, using server Apache CXF and IDE Spring Tool Suite 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, cxf, cxfrs

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-19 21:37:31.513  INFO 2644 --- [           main] com.bhanu.restws.RestwsApplication       : Starting RestwsApplication on DESKTOP-P52KP7P with PID 2644 (D:\Program Files\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.0.RELEASE\restws\target\classes started by win10 in D:\Program Files\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.0.RELEASE\restws)
2020-04-19 21:37:31.515  INFO 2644 --- [           main] com.bhanu.restws.RestwsApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-19 21:37:31.976 ERROR 2644 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:335) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:401) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:286) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:98) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:77) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.bhanu.restws.RestwsApplication.main(RestwsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:325) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

This is my pom file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.bhanu.restws</groupId>
<artifactId>restws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>restws</name>
<description>Patient REST Services</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

//Please help, Thankyou :)

Comment: Check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41562930/415749

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solved my error. I deletes .m2/repository folder, performed maven clean --> maven install and maven update project. Still I am getting same error.

Comment: May you format your answer a bit.