# My project's pom.xml error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

pom.xml

```
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I making web project with spring, jsp, sevlet in eclipse.
but spring-core dependency make trouble.

In `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`
show error

error message is very long... I don't know..

> > Failure to transfer commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from
> >     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> >     repository, 
> >          resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not
> >     transfer artifact 
> >          commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. 
> >          org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from https://
> >          repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> >     interval of
> >     central has 
> >          elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from/to
> >     central
> >     (https://
> >          repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. at
>
> ```
>  org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
> ```
>
> at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
>   at 
>        org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
>   at 
>        org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
>   at 
>        org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
>   at 
>        org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:
>        63) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
>        $2.run(BuildManager.java:735) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
>        $1.run(BuildManager.java:301) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
>   at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:
>        235) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Thanks for helping me.. I'm beginner

Comment: Try clearing your local cache and re-downloading. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache

Comment: Try running the following maven commands -> maven clean install -U, or move the specific package out of the .m2/repository folder

Answer (score -1):

Kindly delete your local .m2 folder located at /Users//.m2 and try to build again.

Comment: There is no need to delete the entire local repository in order to fix this problem. Typically you would execute a command line maven build with the `-U` option to make make maven look for the artefacts again.