# Why pom.xml showing error in Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I m new to Spring Boot.
I have created couple of Spring Starter project for learning.
In my new project I am facing error in pom.xml for line -

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd`

Error is -

Failure to transfer net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.11 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.11 from/to central (https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.11
from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.11 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was
cancelled. at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:193) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:559) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200) at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:629) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:65) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:547) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:511) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:509) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:361) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:312) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:151) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:89) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832) at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316) at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

I have already checked some questions here -

[My project's pom.xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257875/my-projects-pom-xml-error)

[My project's pom.xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257875/my-projects-pom-xml-error)

But none of these resolved error.

Could you please help me on this

Comment: Can you try to build the spring-boot project through command line using mvn command and re-import the project in eclipse.This problem sometimes comes in eclipse and m2 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Your imports are corrupted most probably due to some internet connectivity issues. So if your ide gives you Invalidate Cache and Restart option you can try that.

Best Way is to execute this command from project terminal command line - `mvn clean install -U`

Or you can Delete the related artifacts (or the full local repo) from ~.m2\repository by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ~/.m2/repository and delete that net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy folder. Maven is sensitive with such thing when you maybe have trouble downloading the jar, and the consequent run it is cached.

Or you can try to run maven with -U parameter to force update.