# SpringBoot Startup Error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am making sample project using maven `Spring-boot` application and getting below error:

> Invalid ZIP archive: 
>   C:\Users\Thaku.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.6\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar".

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate quite a bit here before anyone can be of assistance. I would start by clearing your cache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache

Comment: hi i have observed that i am getting above error when i add below tag to the pom.x<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>ml

Comment: Sorted .The Version of parent release didn't  comply with the STS version.Thanks for responding