# Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration.beansEndpoint

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, pom.xml

After adding the dependency of the `spring-boot-starter-actuator and spring-data-rest-hal-browser` in the pom.xml.

Not able to start the spring boot application it is failing with error mentioned below.
Is there any dependency problem with the other modules already used or any specific version i should use

Already tried maven clean and maven install multiple times

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration.beansEndpoint
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:389) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:379) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:114) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration.beansEndpoint
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:442) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration$AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@232204a1]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/audit/InMemoryAuditEventRepository
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.InMemoryAuditEventRepository
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

My pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.shubham.rest.webservices</groupId>
<artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>restful-web-services</name>
<description>Rest project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It looks like Maven has corrupted the `spring-boot-Actuator` jar when it downloaded it. Try deleting it from Maven’s cache and rebuilding your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong while downloading dependencies so you had corrupted jars.

Try clearing `.m2` repository by referring below link.

[How do you clear Apache Maven's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache)