# How to deal with huge .m2 directory in the docker overlay/diff directory?

Tags: linux, maven, docker, memory-management

I have a concept to understand here to solve a problem I am facing with my docker containers and the disk usage by them.

When I dig into the overlay directory of a container, (for example in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ec5c07ba6ae1692ad127173/diff/home/bamboo/.m2/repository) I see a lot of files that are unnecessary consuming the disk space ~200G and I want to understand why these files are still here in this directory.

I am assuming that this has something to do with the docker top most writable layer concept to keep track of the changes. But I want to know if these files are supposed to be deleted by Docker at any point? If not, can we just delete them without impacting the containers?

I have already tried `Docker prune` command trying to delete these files with no luck!

I would appreciate it if someone could share some light on this to help me understand the concept and solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## `docker prune` is for inactive containers only

[`docker prune`](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) clears only unused space. I.e. images, networks and volumes that are not used by active containers.

So, maybe some of active containers use `OverlayFS` layers with `.m2` cache

## `.m2` is for cache

`.m2` directory is intended to store `Maven` repository cache.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409208/5720818) for explanation.
You can clean it using `find` tool

E.g.:

```
sudo find /var/lib/docker/overlay2 -name '.m2' -type d -exec rm -rf {}\repository \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it also a good practice to mount the ".m2" directory to the host directory instead of it writing on the overlay directory? @Yasen

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure why are you need `.m2` in the docker context at all. Since containers recommended for non-persistent usage - why are you use maven inside docker?

Comment: I am working with Bamboo, so the setup is like this: I have a Linux machine on top I have a container with the softwarre like Maven, ANT, etc. And inside the container, I have the Bamboo agent sitting on it which is used to make the builds. so Maven is used in this context. Is there any other efficient way of doing it?