# Failure to deploy 1st Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to just create demp spring boot project but I got an error in pom.xml says:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:FirstProj:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-  parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-  parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

i'm using maven4 with jdk 8 and STS 4

[image]

Comment: `spring-boot-starter- parent` is there a space before `parent`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache