# How to fix IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I keep getting this error whenever I try to run my Spring Application. Can someone please help? Thank you!

I am attaching the stack trace below. I think I am missing some dependency I guess. I googled it out and according to it, there's some issue in the version of the dependencies I have downloaded in pom.xml
I don't know how to fix that. :/

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at Application.RouteConfigurationApplication.main(RouteConfigurationApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:487) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:436) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:517) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:506) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:429) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:525) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:513) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Might be something went wrong while downloading dependencies so you had corrupted jars.Try clear .m2 repository, For how to please follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache

Answer (score 0):

Check your spring versions. The root cause is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`, which is surprising since its a Class that comes with Spring itself. Maybe you use a starter from another version that you run spring, or you are using spring versions incompatible with the spring boot versions you use.