# How long does maven cache artifacts in the local repository?

Tags: maven

The [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local) suggests that "Maven uses [its local repository] as a cache, not a repository".  This [cache can be cleared manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671261/150884), but how long does Maven cache artifacts before refetching artifact metadata or artifacts themselves?

Comment: Simply never except for SNAPSHOT which can be configured by using the updatePolicy in settings.xml (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). For releases it makes no sense cause releases are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven expects non-`-SNAPSHOT` artifacts to be immutable. Once a release has been fetched, Maven will not refresh metadata or artifacts again. Neither will it evict or clear down the cache, although you may wish to do this yourself.

As @khmarbaise's comment notes:

> except for SNAPSHOT which can be configured by using the updatePolicy in settings.xml (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: I don't think it is generally true. Maven checks and downloads the release versions again after some time. I couldn't find a rule when and why it happens.