# How to clear Maven project cache?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How to automatically clear the project build cache (located inside the .m2 folder)? Are there instructions which can be added in de pom.xml file? Can it be triggered by a Maven Clean operation?

I only want to delete the project build from the m2 folder.

Comment: Simply delete the `.m2/repository` folder

Comment: I don't if some commands exist for removing that folder, but it's a good practice to sometimes (in dev) remove this `.m2/repository` folder entirely to check if dependencies are still strong and well declared in the POM file

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-clear-cache

Comment: Why would you like to automatically clear the local cache? Where on the local machine or on the CI ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clear Apache Maven's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache .