# Maven downloading dependencies into project root instead of home/.m2

Tags: maven

Whenever I run mvn in my project dir it always downloads the dependencies into that dir... I want it to download them into the main repo (home/.m2 )

[image]

Comment: I don't see useful information in this picture, can you post the complete log with `-X` enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick google search : [how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916157/how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo).

Run `mvn -X` and check on the first the line the one that start with:

`[DEBUG] Using local repository at *YOUR_LOCAL_REPOSITORY*`

If it is not the folder you want, you can change the value in your global settings or your user settings.

`[DEBUG] Reading global settings from *YOUR_GLOBAL_SETTINGS*`

`[DEBUG] Reading user settings from *YOUR_USER_SETTINGS*`

To change the value you have to add or update the element "localRepository" in one or both of the above settings file.

`<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>`

[Maven - Guide to Configuring Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html)