# Maven install generates meta-data-local.xml instead of meta-data.xml

Tags: java, maven

When I run `maven install -o -X`, maven puts the output (a jar) to the .m2 folder. The problem is that in my case this generates a metadata file named "maven-metadata-local.xml". When I reference this artifact from another maven build, maven complains that the metadata file "maven-metadata.xml" cannot be found (at the exact same location).

So basically I have to questions:

1. Where does the "-local" part come from and what does it exactly mean?
2. How to I make this build work, i.e. tell maven to name the meta-data file "maven-metadata.xml" while building the first artifact or tell maven to look for the file "maven-metadata-local.xml" when resolving the dependencies in the second build?

The dependency in the second pom is:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
      <artifactId>d</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

the location of the jar in the local .m2 directory is

```
.m2/a/b/c/d/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/d-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is the error message:

```
    [DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the metadata ch.*****.*****:*****-server:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml has not been downloaded from it before
[DEBUG] Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the metadata ch.*****.*****:*****-server:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml has not been downloaded from it before
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata ch.*****.*****:*****-project:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/*****/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the metadata ch.*****.*****:*****-project:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml has not been downloaded from it before
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=2, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=17, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=7}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.268 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-29T15:25:03+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project *****-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project ch.*****.*****:*****-assembly:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact ch.*****.*****:*****-project:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project *****-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project ch.*****.*****:*****-assembly:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project ch.*****.*****:*****-assembly:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.*****.*****:*****-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact ch.*****.*****:*****-project:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT has not been downloaded from it before.
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:226)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact ch.*****.*****:*****-project:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT has not been downloaded from it before.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:173)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact ch.*****.*****:*****-project:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT has not been downloaded from it before.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:391)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.RepositoryOfflineException: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultOfflineController.checkOffline(DefaultOfflineController.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.Utils.checkOffline(Utils.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:387)
    ... 41 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: All of this is perfectly normal. What are you trying to do? *When I reference this artifact from another maven build, maven complains* What is the error? Please post your POM file, and the exact steps that you did.

Comment: I get the error message: Could not find metadata ....1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml ...

Comment: That is not the full error message. This error has a cause. That is what is important, and the cause is contained in the message.

Comment: added the stacktrace

Comment: Well there you have it `Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode`. You're running Maven in offline mode, and it's trying to download something, so it fails. This means that the dependency to the installed artifact is incorrect. What is the path of `a.jar` in your local repository? And what is the dependency that you're using later on?

Comment: added info about dependency and jar file in .m2 folder

Comment: Then the local repository used is not the right one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916157/how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo-location to see how to make sure which one is used.