# Caching Maven parent in offline build

Tags: java, maven, docker

**TL/DR: How can I cache the `pom.xml` file's `<parent>` so my build can be run in offline mode?**

I'm using Docker to build a maven project. My goal is to add two steps to the build: one to download all of the dependencies, and another to build the project. Here's what my Dockerfile looks like so far:

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8

# Download the project dependencies (so they can be cached by Docker)
ADD pom.xml /runtime/
WORKDIR /runtime
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
RUN mvn dependency:resolve-plugins

# Mount the local repository
ADD . /runtime

# Build the service
RUN mvn clean package -o -DskipTests
```

<strike>This seems to work fine for the plugins. I checked the `/root/.m2/repository` and everything seems to be in order.</strike>

<strike>Edit: When double checking for the `/root/.m2/repository` directory, it's no longer there. For some reason, Maven isn't saving any of the dependencies to this location.</strike>

**Edit 2: After building the Docker image, there's no `/root/.m2/repository` directory. However, if I run `mvn dependency:go-offline` from within a shell inside the Docker container, the directory is created without a problem.**

When I attempt build my application, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:service:1.2: Cannot access central (http://jcenter.bintray.com) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.M3 has not been downloaded from it before. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.sample:service:1.2 (/runtime/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.oe:graph-service:1.2: Cannot access central (http://jcenter.bintray.com) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.M3 has not been downloaded from it before. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

The problem seems to be that `mvn dependency:go-offline` isn't resolving the parent. When I run the build in offline mode, it breaks.

Here are the relevant portions of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
    </parent>

    ...

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.snapshot</id>
            <name>SpringSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
       ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.scala</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- disabling Spring cloud AWS until proper testing harnesses can be set up -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        ...
    </dependencies>

    ...
</project>
```

Comment: As a side note, this is my first time working with Maven. I inherited this repo and didn't write the `pom.xml` file. If you see any other problems or issues with the `pom.xml` file or my approach, please don't hesitate to point them out!

Comment: `mvn dependency:go-offline` should already download the POM file of the parent and install it in the local repository. I tested with Maven 3.3.9 and it does it (so running in offline mode works afterwards). Which version are you using? Can you verify that the parent POM is present in the local repository at `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.0.M3`?

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well. Maven dependency tree shows that the parent of my pom is not resolved.

Comment: @Tunaki Good call at looking at the `repository` directory. After double checking things, this directory no longer seems to be there. I've added an edit to my question.

Comment: Maven must be using another local repository then, and putting the dependencies at that other repository. Try to get which one it is using with the help of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916157/how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo-location.

Comment: @Tunaki That's so odd. The output from running that command is `/root/.m2/repository`, and when I run it the `repository` directory is created. After digging in a little more, I think I've narrowed down the problem. When running `RUN mvn dependency:go-offline` from the `Dockerfile`, the `repostiroy` directory isn't created (despite downloading all the files). However, when running `mvn dependency:go-offline` form a shell inside the docker container, the `repository` directory is created without a problem.

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with Docker at all, sorry to not be of help on that one :/ This looks like a Docker config issue somewhere though.

Comment: @Tunaki That's okay. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you customize maven's `settings.xml` file you can save your repository files on image.

Create a custom version of `settings.xml`, with the `localRepository` setting modified, like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository -->
  <localRepository>/usr/share/maven/repo</localRepository>
...
```

Then override the default configuration when building your image:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

RUN mvn clean package
```

Now your repository is stored in `/usr/share/maven/repo`.

### Using onbuild

You can also create a base image using [ONBUILD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/onbuild), this will allow to have custom configured images for every maven project.

Like this:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD ADD . /usr/src/app

ONBUILD RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

ONBUILD RUN mvn clean package
```

Then build the image:

```
docker build -t mvn_bldr .
```

This will create a *template* for other maven images. Then you can create your custom *downstream* image with:

```
FROM mvn_bldr
```

If you want to customize your image further you can add more instructions, every instruction of the template will be triggered after the `FROM mvn_bldr` command, as in the docs:

> The trigger will be executed in the context of the downstream build,
>   as if it had been inserted immediately after the FROM instruction in
>   the downstream Dockerfile.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the suggestions. I think this elegantly solves our problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem like using `RUN` with Docker is like executing commands in a shell script, but it's not. Every instance of `RUN` gets applied to a new container that results from the changes created by the previous command. So each command is executing inside of a new container context.

Dockerifles can contain a `VOLUME` reference, which mounts an external directory inside the Docker container. If there were any files inside the volume, those files are wiped out. If you don't explicitly specify a volume, Docker is happy to instead create an empty folder.

While my Dockerfile doesn't contain an explicit reference to a `VOLUME`, its parent does. So, even though my `mvn dependency:go-offline` command was running, those files were being wiped out in the next step by the `VOLUME` specified in the [`docker-maven` `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/jdk-8/Dockerfile).

In the end, I couldn't find a good way to make the `maven` Docker image work, so I switched to the `openjdk` image and installed `maven` via `apt-get` instead.