# How to get maven local repository location from java code

Tags: java, maven

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916157/how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo-location) solution to get the local repository path in my java code and everything was working fine until my employer added "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" to the system environment variables (in windows). Now my output looks something like

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
c:\users\me\.m2\repository
```

Given that I cant unset this environment variable (i tried to put a single space in user environment variables but from my java code it just re instates the environment variable each time the process is re-run) is there any option to mute this?

Below is the command i used in my java code

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout
```

[I know](https://superuser.com/questions/585695/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message) from my code i can trim out everything from "Picked up" to new line. But is there a better way?

Comment: Is this a Maven plugin? If not, why do you need the local repository?

Comment: We have a helper program which deploys jars once it is built into foundry Palantir. I havent written it, so done know the full details, but that is the general idea. I can do some tweaks, but wont be able to re-engineer the existing solution unfortunately.